# Unit testing a Swift app which is using Parse.com

Tags: swift, unit-testing, parse-platform

I've a sample app using Parse.com as back end and now I'm writing some unit tests.
As said in the Parse documentation, when I subclassed `PFObject` I implemented the initialize method:

```
override class func initialize() {
    struct Static {
        static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
    }
    dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }
}
```

When I run my unit tests my app crashes in the initialize method with the following error:

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to register both TargetName.MyObject and TargetNameTests.MyObject as the native PFObject subclass of MyObject. Cannot determine the right class to use because neither inherits from the other.*

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I have found a way to make this work is not to include the subclass in the test target and to declare the subclass and its variables and methods public. And also import your application target

```
#import MyProject
#import Parse
#import XCTest

public class MySubClass: PFObject, PFSubclassing {
     @NSManaged public var name: String?

     public static func parseClassName() -> String {
       return "MySubClass"
     }
}
```

Then in the test file you need to call the class as such:

```
let testObject = MyProject.MyClass()
```

Comment: They don't have to be public if you use the @testable attribute to import the module: https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH4-SW11